# How to determine if a string contains a specific date in any format?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an object with property A of type DATE and property B of type string.  A requirement is that property B may not contain the string representation of property A.

right now I have the very simplistic approach of validating:

```
public function Validate() as boolean
    if b.contains(a.toString("[format1]", CultureInfo....)
      return false
    end if

    if b.contains(a.toString("[format2]", CultureInfo...)
       return false
    end if

    'etc

    return true

end function
```

But something in that approach feels wrong. Date.TryParse won't work because B may have more in it than JUST A.

Is there some approach that would let me validate B without typing out every possible datetime format (in a variety of Cultures) for A?

I don't care of the solution is VB.net or C#.

**Clarification:**
There are a few format restrictions on property B.   It won't allow the typical date delimiters of forward slash or dot or even space.  So I expect to see the date in something like mmddyyyy and ddmmyyyy or even MONddyyyy, etc.  I'm not worried about anything except for month, day, and year.

I could just keep a list of possible formats and iterate through it, though my concern is that I might overlook a potential format that way.

**Additional Clarification**
Property A is a date value, not a string.  So format is not determined by the user - it is determined by my validation process.  So in the following examples, B should NOT validate.

```
A = Date(1962, 01, 22)

B = 01221962MyNewString
or
B = Mystring19620122value
or
B = Jan221962mystring
etc.
```

There are many possibilities for the string representation that I would need to exclude.  Although I suppose, I don't need to exclude "the22ofjanuary1962".

I could use regular expressions - but the same issue exists.  I simply have to think of every possible string representation and check for it.  I was hoping something in the .Net framework already existed and I could use it. But sounds like no such luck.

**ANSWER:**
I marked Blam's post as the answer.  It got me really close, especially once I added a regular expression. I iterate through all possible cultures.  I then go through all the relevant standard datetime formats (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx), strip all non alphanumberic characters, and do the compare.

Not saying it caught everything, but all my unit tests pass so it caught all the ones I could think of today.  and I could always add custom datetime formats later if the need becomes apparent.

**Here's my solution.**

```
Dim allCultures As CultureInfo()

allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
Dim rgx = New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")

For Each ci As CultureInfo In allCultures
 If B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("d", ci), "")) Or _
                B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("D", ci), "")) Or _
                B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("M", ci), "")) Or _
                B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("s", ci), "")) Or _
                B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("u", ci), "")) Or _
                B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("Y", ci), "")) Or _
                B.Contains(rgx.Replace(Me.A.ToString("g", ci), "")) Then
                Return False
     End If
Next

Return True
```

Comment: proberty B **cannot** contain DATETIME, since it is string

Comment: If "B" is free form text you probably out of luck... "This year on the second day of the first month of spring ..." may be hard to match with 2014-03-02 :) Do you have any format restrictions on "property B"?

Comment: @AmitJoki you can indeed read it this way too, but title (at least for me) looks like "string can't contain particular date (string representation of the date) in any format"

Comment: sorry for the confusion - yes - I'm referring to the date.tostring(format) representation of the date.

Comment: Is this checking to see if someone has entered their birthdate as their password?

Comment: Alexei - I'll answer your question in the body of my question.

Comment: what if by using REGEX ?
You need a general Regular expression which includes all the date format. http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Comment: First problem is that you are dealing with properties and not objects.  B is a string, the moment you convert types (Date to String) it's now perfectly legal for A to be 'contained' in B.  You need to add extra code to adhere to Type checking and prevent B's from operating on A's.  Otherwise there is no way to know if B is acting on an A.  You can add extra code to your property set methods or convert A and/or B to Class's and provide appropriate assignment operators that do the appropriate type checking before concatenating

Comment: 1. Store an array of possible DateTime formats i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and more, and use regex to parse the input. 2. If the regex fails, throw an error saying the format is incorrect. 3. I would also specify to the user what formats are accepted and what's not to spare them the confusion.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage OP is not looking for any date format.  OP is looking for a specific date in multiple formats.

Comment: @Rawling...what what?  Did I misundersand the question?...nm - I seed the OP has been modified from the original vagueness.

Comment: There are characters other than a-zA-Z in some of those cultures.

Comment: Blam - that's an excellent point. So people should adapt to their own circumstances as appropriate.  However, our variable B will only contain a-zA-Z, so I got lucky with this circumstance. I'll make a note to revisit if we ever loosen the specs on that field.

Comment: You might be able to use CultureInfo.TextInfo.ANSICodePage to get only latin.  But processing non latin would not break ti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just enumerate cultures

```
CultureTypes[] mostCultureTypes = new CultureTypes[] {
            CultureTypes.NeutralCultures, 
            CultureTypes.SpecificCultures, 
            CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures, 
            CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture, 
            CultureTypes.ReplacementCultures, 
            };
CultureInfo[] allCultures;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1962, 01, 22);

// Get and enumerate all cultures.
allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
foreach (CultureInfo ci in allCultures)
{
    // Display the name of each culture.
    Console.WriteLine("Culture: {0}", ci.Name);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Console.WriteLine("Displaying short date for {0} culture:",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("   {0} (Short Date String)",
                        dt.ToShortDateString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Even with that it appears you are not allowing spaces so you would need remove spaces.
You are not allowing certain delimiters so would need to remove them
You state any data format but you are really looking for specific date formats.
But you don't want to identify the date formats because you might miss one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one option is to keep your list of possible formats somewhere, e.g. some constants or in a config file, then you can iterate over that list and make a new list with your date in each of those formats. Once you have that, you can check if your string contains any of those values.